# Parse json in python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I need help with parsing JSON in python.

I have a JSON code:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":791279,
      "tags":[  
         {  
            "userId":369,
            "name":"SMB"
         }
      ]
   }
]
[  
   {  
      "id":791280,
      "tags":[  
         {  
            "userId":369,
            "name":"FIBER"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

and the output should be "id" and "name" in "tags" group. Unfortunately, I can't find a solution. ID is not problem (`print(data[0]["id"]`)

`print(data[0]["tags"]["name"])` --> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

`print(data = data[0]["tags"][1])` --> IndexError: list index out of range

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Notice that `tags` is also an array. Thus: `print(data[0]["tags"][0]["name"])`.

Comment: Thanks - it's work!

Answer (score 0):

```js
// correct syntax for data
data = [[  
   {  
      "id":791279,
      "tags":[  
         {  
            "userId":369,
            "name":"SMB"
         }
      ]
   }
],
[  
   {  
      "id":791280,
      "tags":[  
         {  
            "userId":369,
            "name":"FIBER"
         }
      ]
   }
]
]

// first access the array-element at from data -> 0th entry is again an array of obejcts so access that -> then access tags property from obejct whcih in turn is an array again -> access 0th element -> query relevant keys.
console.log(data[0][0]["tags"][0]["name"])

// for python, replace console.log with print
```

Comment: I can't change JSON - it's output from REST API.